# HTML: How to create a scalable layout with elements glued to the edges

Tags: html, css, layout, extjs

I am trying to do something like this:

```
  :                                                  :
..:..................................................:..
  :B               <center>B</center>               B:
  :                                                  :
  :   Sed et velit sit amet eros pulvinar auctor.    :
  :   Integer tristique facilisis velit, vitae       :
  :   rhoncus neque auctor sit amet. Ut              :
  :   condimentum porta ipsum, eu luctus quam        :
  :B  tincidunt ut. Sed id dolor eros. Aenean       B:
  :   semper volutpat leo, vel euismod tellus        :
  :   feugiat vitae. Aenean varius, ipsum eu         :
  :   fringilla tincidunt, leo nunc feugiat          :
  :   neque, vitae imperdiet sapien orci ut ipsum.   :
  :                                                  :
  :B               <center>B</center>               B:
..:..................................................:..
  :                                                  :
```

The **B**'s are small buttons, not identical but very similar in size.

I want to put this inside an *Ext.Window* which is resizable, and thus it needs to be able to scale accordingly. The **UI** feeling should be that the buttons are glued to the sides of the window frame - thus the window appears as a normal *Ext.Window* with buttons at the edges.

I have tried doing this using `<div>`'s combined with *relative* and *absolute* positioning, *float*'ing and the four *left*, *right*, *bottom* and *top* positioning.

But my combinations so far haven't done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [anchor](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.AnchorLayout) and [hbox](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.HBoxLayout) layout.

I think it would a little be tricky but if you use more than one panel it should be possible

A possibility would be to use the hbox layout and make 3 panels

The window would have a anchor layout, so you can make the three subpanel resize depending on the window. The subpanel would have hbox layout and the central cell with the `flex:1`.

You should take a loot at the [layout manager](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) and try to combine the layouts to make what you need.

make something like this

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
+ +                  HBOX layout panel 1                           + +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
+ +                  HBOX layout panel 1                           + +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
+ +                  HBOX layout panel 2                           + +
+ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In JavaScript it would give:

```
{
    anchor: '100% 5%'
    layout: 'hbox'
    items:[ 
        {
           html: 'button',
           width: 50,
        },
        {
          html: 'button 2',
          flex: 1
        },
        {   
          html: 'button 3'.
          width: 50
        }
    ]
},{
    anchor: '100% 90%'
    layout: 'hbox'
    items:[ 
        {
           html: 'button',
           width: 50,
        },
        {
          html: 'lorem ipsu some text',
          flex: 1
        },
        {   
          html: 'button 3'.
          width: 50
        }
    ]
},{
    anchor: '100% 5%'
    layout: 'hbox'
    items:[ 
        {
           html: 'button',
           width: 50,
        },
        {
          html: 'button 2',
          flex: 1
        },
        {   
          html: 'button 3'.
          width: 50
        }
    ]
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ofcourse - why haven't I thought of looking at *Ext* own layouts. Thanks for pointing at the wall infront of me - I will try it out ;)

Comment: It worked fine. I had to make it a bit more complicated to get the buttons to not stretch (using more elements in the `hbox`) and vertically align the side buttons using a `vbox`. Thanks a lot :D